# LocationManager requestLocationUpdates and timertask in android

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
if (gps_enabled) {
        Log.e("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$",
                "GPS is enabled requestion location updates... interval value is: "
                        + interval);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                locationListenerGps);
    }
    else{
        if (network_enabled) {
            Log.e("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$",
                    "Network is enabled requestion location updates... interval value is: "
                            + interval);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,
                    0, locationListenerNetwork);
        }
    }
```

with that code I can get the location(at least using the network provider! (another issue on another post))
I would like to get notifications in a regular interval say every one hour, but passing the parameter to requestLocationUpdates doesn't guarantee that the interval will be maintained (at least that my tests showned,since I expected update every minute but got a lot of updates instead of one!)
so i thought of using a timerTask and schedule it, I now have

```
timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getLocation();
        }

    }, 0, 180000);// 3 minutesr...
```

where getLocation is the method that I called previously called, but when the timer calls that method then nothing happens, the logs stop at this point

```
Log.e("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$",
                    "Network is enabled requestion location updates... interval value is: "
                            + interval);
```

and I never get notified about my location.
any Ideas?

Comment: anyone? this is really weird and it driving me mad. why I am not able to get location updates when I call them from a timerTask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok took me a while but I have found the solution to this,as the documentation says you can only request location updates from the location manager from a looper thread, that means that when the timer task is called you have to obtain a message and send the message to a handler and the handler would be responsible for requesting location updates.