# How to update the location after the particular time in android?

Tags: android, location

I am working on location based application for android .In that i want to check  GPS is enabled in my mobile or not.If enabled means find the location based on GPS otherwise i want to check after five minutes again disabled means i want to find the location using network provider

Please any one give me Idea for that with some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here. I am not using a timer like you want so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589963/locationmanager-requestlocationupdates-and-timertask-in-android) is a post where it is being used as you are describing.